# How to convert a pdf to image in Unity/C# using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, pdf

I'm working on a Unity project which requires me to show PDFs within the project. To do this I need to convert it to an image first and then display that (the only way to show a PDF is to buy an asset on the store it seems). However, this seems quite difficult to do in C#. I've tried a number of libraries but have had no luck. However this conversion seems extremely easy to do in Javascript. Is there any way to execute Javascript code from within a C# program?
So for example, I download my PDF with an API call on my C# program, then execute some Javascript code to open up the PDF in the background and save the canvas element as a png/jpeg for me to use back in my C# program?

Answer (score 1):

For your question "Using javascript inside Unity"
You can review this [page](https://pleasenophp.github.io/posts/using-real-javascript-with-unity.html)

But there is a way to view pdf files that I used from a long time ago and it was fine the [package](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/pdf-renderer-32815)